# Does spring-security-saml handle SPN format of audience restrictions?

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

We are using `spring-security-saml2-core 1.0.1.RELEASE` to authenticate with our ADFS running in the Azure cloud.

The authentication is failing as Azure is pre-pending `'spn:'` to the start of the `EntityId` in the `<AudienceRestriction>` part of the auth response. This then causes the class `org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl` to fail the request as it expects the audience string to match the `EntityId` exactly.

For example, if the SP `EntityId` is `ca58424a-3338-4ac2-81ec-fe4a822f7fcd` and the auth request is successful, Azure returns this in the EntityId in the audience restriction response:

```
  <Conditions NotBefore="2015-10-21T14:24:41.745Z" NotOnOrAfter="2015-10-21T15:24:41.745Z">
     <AudienceRestriction>
        <Audience>spn:ca58424a-3338-4ac2-81ec-fe4a822f7fcd</Audience>
     </AudienceRestriction>
  </Conditions>
```

Not sure why Azure does this but this [Azure blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/enhancements-to-windows-azure-active-directory-preview/) does mention Azure using the SPN format.

Is this a known issue, and is there any fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by pre-pending `spn:` to the beginning of the `EntityID` in the web app config. When this passed to Azure it must check for and remove the string before comparing the `EntityID`.